# redirect searchglassfilms.com to www.searchglassfilms.com using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain searchglassfilms.com, the problem which I'm facing is searchglassfilms.com isn't responding. How to redirect all the request for searchglassfilms.com to www.searchglassfilms.com? I know it can be done with .htaccess but I've not been able to find a solution till now.

> [searchglassfilms.com](http://searchglassfilms.com) is not working [www.searchglassfilms.com](http://www.searchglassfilms.com) is working why?

check here I have done something :

```
    # turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^[^.]*?\.?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.                         [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         http://www.%1/$1                [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^searchglassfilms\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.searchglassfilms.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^searchglassfilms\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.searchglassfilms\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$


# Redirect non-www to www

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    # If https send to https://www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^searchglassfilms.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.searchglassfilms.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If http send to http://www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^searchglassfilms.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.searchglassfilms.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> can someone identify what's going wrong in .htaccess file which is on root directory?

Comment: "searchglassfilms.com isn't responding." - it _is_ responding, it's just that it's not responding in the way you expect (check the network response / view source). What is curious though is that `https://searchglassfilms.com` is being redirected correctly!? Have you had this problem from the outset, or only after trying to implement `.htaccess`? Your `.htaccess` directives are a bit of a mess - you have multiple directives (some of which are incomplete) all trying to do the same thing? Is this really all in the same file? Why are you keeping HTTP and HTTPS separate?

Comment: Sir, I do not know much about .htaccess. I have done whatever I got from the internet.

Comment: Yes, www.searchglassfilms.com is being redirected correctly but  searchglassfilms.com is not being redirected correctly. why not they both are same?